# How to coalesce array columns in Spark dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
id | myStruct
___________________
1  | [val1, val2]
___________________
2  | [val3, val4]
___________________
1  | [val5, val6]
```

I would like to group all myStructs that share the same id into an array column of myStructs. So, the above dataframe should become

```
id | myStruct
__________________________________
1  | [[val1, val2], [val5, val6]]
__________________________________
2  | [[val3, val4]]
```

I know there is an array function, but that only converts each column into an array of size 1. How do I coalesce the resulting arrays?

I am using Spark 1.5.2 in a Scala shell.

Given that I am using Spark 1.5.2, I cannot use collect_list or collect_set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use Spark 1.5 and you cannot upgrade the simplest option is `RDD.groupByKey`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

val rows = df.rdd
  .map { case Row(id, myStruct) => (id, myStruct) }
  .groupByKey
  .map { case (id, myStructs) => Row(id, myStructs) }

val schema =  StructType(Seq(
  df.schema("id"),
  StructField("myStructs", ArrayType(df.schema("myStruct").dataType))
))

sqlContext.createDataFrame(rows, schema)
```

It can be generalized by converting to "pairs" like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.struct

df.select(
  struct($"key1", $"key2", ..., $"keyn").alias("id"),
  struct($"val1", $"val2", ..., $"valn").alias("myStruct")
)
```

Answer (score 1):

In Spark 2.0+ you can use `collect_list` to accomplish this:

```
scala> val df = sc.parallelize(Seq((1, ("v1", "v2")), (2, ("v3", "v4")), (1, ("v5", "v6")))).toDF("id", "myStruct")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, myStruct: struct<_1: string, _2: string>]

scala> df.show
+---+--------+
| id|myStruct|
+---+--------+
|  1| [v1,v2]|
|  2| [v3,v4]|
|  1| [v5,v6]|
+---+--------+

scala> df.groupBy("id").agg(collect_list($"myStruct")).show
+---+----------------------+                                                    
| id|collect_list(myStruct)|
+---+----------------------+
|  1|    [[v1,v2], [v5,v6]]|
|  2|             [[v3,v4]]|
+---+----------------------+
```

However in Spark 1.5.2 you would need something like this:

```
scala> val df2 = df.select($"id", $"myStruct._1".as("p1"), $"myStruct._2".as("p2"))
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, p1: string, p2: string]

scala> df2.show
+---+---+---+
| id| p1| p2|
+---+---+---+
|  1| v1| v2|
|  2| v3| v4|
|  1| v5| v6|
+---+---+---+

scala> val rdd = df2.rdd.map{case Row(id: Int, p1: String, p2: String) => (id, (p1, p2))}
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(Int, (String, String))] = MapPartitionsRDD[47] at map at <console>:32

scala> val finalDF = rdd.groupByKey.map(x => (x._1, x._2.toList)).toDF("id", "structs")
finalDF: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [id: int, structs: array<struct<_1:string,_2:string>>]

scala> finalDF.show
+---+------------------+
| id|           structs|
+---+------------------+
|  1|[[v1,v2], [v5,v6]]|
|  2|         [[v3,v4]]|
+---+------------------+
```

Comment: Correct, but I think `collect_list` was only introduced in Spark 1.6.0, hence OP can't use it (Spark 1.5.2) unless they upgrade...

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I cannot upgrade my spark, so I can't use collect_list.